# Evitar redireccionamiento de beginform al dar submit

Tags: c#, jquery, razor

tengo el siguiente codigo.

```
@model IpsAuthorizer.Models.KeyStatuses
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("/SaveOrEditKeyStatuses", "Catalogo", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return SubmitForm(this)" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Nuevo Estatus LLave</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xl-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtIdEstatusLLave" class="control-label">Id Estatus LLave:</label>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.KeyStatusId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @name = "txtIdEstatusLLave" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KeyStatusId)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xl-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtDescripcion" class="control-label">Descripción:</label>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @name = "txtDescripcion" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSave">Guardar</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSave").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                success: function (res) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log("HOLA");
                    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Quiero que al darle click en el submit el form me matenga la vista actual y no me redireccione a la respuesta del metodo SaveOrEditKeyStatuses que es el siguiente:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveOrEditKeyStatuses(KeyStatuses param)
    {
        try
        {
            if (param.Id == 0)
            {
                this.db.KeyStatuses.Add(param);
                this.db.SaveChanges();
                //    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                return PartialView();

                // return Json(new { success = true, message = "Guardado Sastifactoriamente" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                this.db.Entry(param).State = EntityState.Modified;
                this.db.SaveChanges();
                return PartialView(Json(new { success = true, message = "Guardado Sastifactoriamente" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
                //return Json(new { success = true, message = "Actualizado Sastifactoriamente" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return PartialView(Json(new { success = true, message = "Guardado Sastifactoriamente" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
        //    return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error" + e.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

En el jquery lo tengo de esta manera.

```
   $('#btn_nuevo').off().on('click', (event) => {
                $('.modal-content').load("/Catalogo/SaveOrEditKeyStatuses", function () {
                    $('#myModal').modal("show");
                });
            });
```

Para ver si alguien conoce alguna manera, de evitar este recargue ya que cuando le doy guardar en mi modal me sale  { success = true, message = "Guardado Sastifactoriamente" } este json y una ventana en blanco, redireccionando y eso es lo que no quiero, solo quiero cerrar la modal para poder continuar el flujo normal de trabajo. Queria saber si esto es posible o no hay solución para esto.

Answer (score 0):

Te faltaria añadir el `event.preventdefault()` para anular las acciones del boton.

```
$('#btn_nuevo').off().on('click', (event) => {
    event.preventdefault()

    $('.modal-content').load("/Catalogo/SaveOrEditKeyStatuses", function () {
        $('#myModal').modal("show");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero deberías cambiar la firma de tu método POST, debería devolver un **JsonResult**, no un **ActionResult**, es decir te quedará de la siguiente manera:

```
public JsonResult SaveOrEditKeyStatuses(KeyStatuses param)
```

Como bien tienes comentado en el código deberá devolver JsonResult ya que eso es lo que definimos como devolución del método, por lo tanto tendrás:

```
 return new JsonResult() { Data = new { Ok = true } };
```

Ahora como bien definiste la acción del Submit, deberás hacer algunas modificaciones para que lleguen a tu método POST y procesar los datos:

```
            $("#btnSave").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveOrEditKeyStatuses")',
                data: data,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (res) {
                    if (data.Ok) {
                        console.log("HOLA");
                    } else {
                        console.log(data.Errores);
                        $.smallBox({
                            title: "Error",
                            content: "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> <i>Hubo un error " + data.Errores + "</i>",
                            color: "#C46A69",
                            iconSmall: "fa fa-times fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
                            timeout: 4000
                        });
                    }
        }).always(function () {
                $("#myModal").modal("hide");
        })
```